# Sequelize FindOrCreate function with OR condition

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a login/registration system using NodeJs & Sequelize. When I take the post data from the user, I would like to do a FindOrCreate query, but one that includes an OR.

```
db.User.findOrCreate({ 
      username : desiredUsername,
      email: emailAddress
    })
```

This executes the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`username`='username' AND `users`.`email`='emailaddress' LIMIT 1;
```

How would I change the AND part to OR? I need to stop the registration process if either statement is correct.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Op.or` operator which will check if either `username` OR `email` exist:

```
const Op = require('Sequelize').Op

User.findOrCreate({
  where: { [Op.or]: [{username: desiredUsername}, {email: emailAddress}] },
  defaults: {firstName, lastName}
})
.then(arr => {
  // the first element is the user
  const user = arr[0]
  // the second element tells us if the user was newly created
  const wasCreated = arr[1]

  // do something with the user data
}
```

Syntax operators reference in the Sequelize docs:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators

Answer (score 0):

Seems you will need to break it into a separate find and create operation:

```
db.User.find({
    where: Sequelize.or({ username: desiredUsername }, { email: emailAddress })
}).success(function (user) {
    if (!user) {
        db.User.create({ username: desiredUsername, email: emailAddress });
    }
});
```